# Cant set label text in .xib file from parent - Swift

Tags: swift

I am having trouble trying to access elements in my .xib file from the parent view controller. My code is as follows:

GraphScrollViewController.swift

```
class GraphScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    var graphScrollMenu: CAPSPageMenu?
    var controllerArray: [UIViewController] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var weekViewController : RecentWeekGraphViewController = RecentWeekGraphViewController(nibName: "RecentRulesWeekGraphViewController", bundle: nil)
        weekViewController.title = "Week"
        controllerArray.append(weekViewController)

        var monthViewController : RecentMonthGraphViewController = RecentMonthGraphViewController(nibName: "RecentMonthGraphViewController", bundle: nil)
        monthViewController.title = "Month"
        controllerArray.append(monthViewController)

        var parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
            .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0)),
            .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0)),
            .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)),
            .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0)),
            .UnselectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)),
            .MenuItemFont(UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 15.0)!),
            .MenuHeight(40.0),
            .MenuItemWidth(90.0),
            .CenterMenuItems(true)
        ]

        graphScrollMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
        self.view.addSubview(graphScrollMenu!.view)
    }

}
```

RecentWeekGraphViewController.swift

```
class RecentWeekGraphViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var xibTestLabel: UILabel!

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
```

When I try to set the xibTestLabel text from GraphScrollView.swift using weekViewController.xibTestLabel.text = "some text" I get:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
```

My outlets all seem to be connected correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Which iOS SDK/Xcode you are using to build the app ?

Comment: Are you having the same problem with monthViewController ?

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to access `xibTestLabel` in `GraphScrollViewController`?

Comment: Have you checked class name of assign .XIBs?

Comment: @hennes - Yep, in GraphScrollViewController

Comment: @Chetan Bhalara - Yep. Checked class names. I can access the label if I do println("\(weekViewController.xibTestLabel?.text)") but it shows as nil so its like it hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Xcode7 beta 4.
Create a string variable and assign the value from outside and set it on the viewdidload

```
var weekViewController : RecentWeekGraphViewController = RecentWeekGraphViewController(nibName: "RecentRulesWeekGraphViewController", bundle: nil)
        weekViewController.title = "Week"
weekViewController.labeltext = "Title"
```

In RecentWeekGraphViewController.swift

```
 var labeltext: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 self.labelTitle.text = labeltext
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

The problem is IBOutlet get connected when presenting the viewcontroller. If you want to access the IBOutlet directly you can do inside presentViewController completion handler

```
  self.presentViewController(weekViewController, animated: true, completion: {         weekViewController.labelTitle.text = "title two"
});
```

Comment: Nope. I renamed a few things but missed this one. Still causes the same issue. I can run the myMethod function ok but just can't change the label text.

Comment: @puks1978 Updated the answer

Comment: Still saving lives! Thank you!